# Recyclerview dataset does not change on fragment start

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView on my fragment that gets its data from an ArrayList in an object named Datasource. I want to get new items from Cloud Firestore when fragment gets started, so I created a function named getAllProducts however I can only get items when I click the bottom navigation bar.

I almost tried every answer to another question. I tried to reload fragment onCreate, I created a navigation action to fragment itself, I added a function in RecyclerView adapter that gets data from getAllProducts function and notifyDataSetChanged(). I make getAllProduct returns array list and used it as data in RecyclerView. None of them worked.

When app is started:

[image: App started]

When clicked home:

[image: Clicked home]

Here related code

ProductAdapter.kt

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productList: ArrayList<ProductItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>() {

    inner class ProductViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val productImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPhoto)
        val productName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName)
        val productRatingBar: RatingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2)
        val productRating: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingint)
        val storeName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productStoreName)
        val productPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice)

    }



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item,
        parent,false)

        return ProductViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = productList[position]
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                view ->
            val action = ProductFragmentDirections.actionProductFragmentToParticularProductFragment2(currentItem)
            view.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
        holder.productImage.setImageResource(currentItem.productImageResource)
        holder.productName.text = currentItem.productName
        holder.productRatingBar.rating = currentItem.productRating.toFloat()
        holder.productRating.text = currentItem.productRating.toString()
        holder.storeName.text = currentItem.storeName
        holder.productPrice.text = currentItem.productPrice.toString().plus("$")

    }


    override fun getItemCount() = productList.size
}
```

Datasource.kt

```
object Datasource {

    var productList = arrayListOf(

        ProductItem(R.drawable.attach_money,"Sahibinden aerator",4.5,"Serhat Yilmaz",8),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.email,"dus kitapları",3.0,"nerhat Yilmaz",9),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.passwordicon,"h files",1.5,"berhat Yilmaz",77),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.category,"piyasemen",5.0,"xerhat Yilmaz",55),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.attach_money,"Sahibinden sasfaf",1.5,"kerhat Yilmaz",11),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.email,"tus kitapları",3.0,"uerhat Yilmaz",21),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.passwordicon,"f files",1.5,"yerhat Yilmaz",47),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.category,"anguldruva",2.0,"terhat Yilmaz",35),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.email,"tus2 kitaplarım",3.0,"werhat Yilmaz",78),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.passwordicon,"endobox",2.5,"Zerhat Yilmaz",95),
        ProductItem(R.drawable.category,"basplak",4.0,"Ferhat Yilmaz",12)

    )

    fun loadProduct(): ArrayList<ProductItem>{
        return productList
    }
}
```

ProductFragment.kt

```
class ProductFragment : Fragment() {
    private val myDataset = Datasource.productList
    private val adapter = ProductAdapter(myDataset)



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_product)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        FireStoreClass().getAllProducts()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }



}
```

FireStoreClass().getAllProducts()

```
private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

fun getAllProducts() {


    mFireStore.collection(Constants.PRODUCTS)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            documents ->
            val list = arrayListOf<ProductItem>()
            for (document in documents){

                val product = document.toObject(ProductItem::class.java)
                list.add(product)

            }
            Datasource.productList = list
            }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            //Toast.makeText(activity, "Can not get Product! ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

}
```

in case you need to see:

NavigateActivity.kt

```
class NavigateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigate)
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavView)
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        //val action = HomeFragmentDirections


    }


}
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/product_Fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/product_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.fragments.ProductFragment"
        android:label="products_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/products_fragment" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_productFragment_to_particularProductFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/particularProductFragment" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_productFragment_Reload"
            app:destination="@id/product_Fragment" />



    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addPostNavActivity"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.AddActivity"
        android:label="addpost"
        tools:layout="@layout/addpost" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addPostNavActivity_to_productFragment"
            app:destination="@id/product_Fragment" />
    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/userActivity"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.UserActivity"
        android:label="userlayout"
        tools:layout="@layout/userlayout" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bucketFragment"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.fragments.BucketFragment"
        android:label="bucketlayout"
        tools:layout="@layout/bucketlayout" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/particularProductFragment"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.fragments.ParticularProductFragment"
        android:label="product_layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/product_layout">
        <argument
            android:name="navProductItem"
            app:argType="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.models.ProductItem" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_bucketFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bucketFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_messageActivity"
            app:destination="@id/messageActivity" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_feedbacksFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/feedbacksFragment2" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/messageActivity"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.MessageActivity"
        android:label="messagelayout"
        tools:layout="@layout/messagelayout" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedbacksFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.TheDentalSupplies.fragments.FeedbacksFragment"
        android:label="feedbacks_layout"
        tools:layout="@layout/feedbacks_layout" />

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase API is asynchronous. So any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the onSuccess() method, or be called from there. Assigning the `list` object inside this method:

```
Datasource.productList = list
```

Doesn't mean that it will assign it immediately. This code will always be triggered after calling getAllProducts() method is called when the data is finished loading. So the best option that you have is to create the following objects like this:

```
private val myDataset = Datasource.productList
private val adapter = ProductAdapter(myDataset)
```

And inside `onViewCreated`:

```
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_product)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
FireStoreClass().getAllProducts()
```

Inside the getAllProducts() method, simply do the following:

```
fun getAllProducts() {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.PRODUCTS)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents){
                val product = document.toObject(ProductItem::class.java)
                myDataset.add(product)

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Can not get Product! ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

}
```

This means that you notify the adapter only when you got all the necessary data from the database.

Since you are using Kotlin, I think you might also be interested in this article:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But it still do not load products on app start. Where exactly should i add FireStoreClass().getAllProducts() ? since my english is not so good, hope i didnt missed something from your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Just forgot to add `FireStoreClass().getAllProducts()` . Please check my updated answer. And btw, your English is really good ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work. Still doesnt loads when app got started and i dont know why . Thanks for answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't provide enough information so I can help you further. Does the Toast message inside onFailure show something? Have you tried to move the four lines of code from on `onViewCreated` inside `onCreateView`? Does it work that way?

Comment: When i added four lines to the onCreateView i got this error     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ProductFragment{1336db9} (0bd85290-7fbe-4464-89cf-046e81c43e07 id=0x7f0a0162) did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().

Comment: Add all those lines of code before `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_fragment, container, false)`. Does it work?

Comment: And when i added four lines to the onViewCreated, Recyclerview loads the products without the items on firebase, after that i got the toast message which inside of onsuccesslistener.

Comment: Are you sure you have added `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the onSuccess? It's very important to notify the adapter about the changes.

Comment: yes it look like this .addOnSuccessListener {
                    documents ->
                for (document in documents){
                    val product = document.toObject(ProductItem::class.java)
                    if (product !in myDataset){
                        myDataset.add(product)
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Product recieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

Comment: Does `Toast.makeText(activity, "Product recieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` show something?

Comment: yes i get this toast 3-4 seconds after recyclerview loads but dataset doesnt get changed.

Comment: If you also add the else part of `if (product !in myDataset)` is it triggered?

Comment: yes i added this  Toast.makeText(activity, "if statement is true!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  i have 5 documents in collection and i got this toast 5 times but items didnt appers on recyclerview

Comment: If the else part is triggered, it means that your list already contains data. So try to clear the list before add new data, right?

Comment: Finally i found a way to do it, not the best solution but does the job. if (Constants.REPEAT < 1){
            Constants.REPEAT = Constants.REPEAT + 1
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"got here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val bottom = view.findNavController()
                bottom.navigate(R.id.action_product_Fragment_self)
            },5000)
        }

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a way to do it, not the best solution but does the job.

Constants.kt

```
object Constants {
    var REPEAT:Int = 0}
```

inside ProductFragment.kt

```
if (Constants.REPEAT < 1){
            Constants.REPEAT = Constants.REPEAT + 1
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"got here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val bottom = view.findNavController()
                bottom.navigate(R.id.action_product_Fragment_self)
            },5000)
        }
```

Comment: Delaying the operation with 5000 milliseconds isn't a solution at all. How about taking 5001 milliseconds to read the data?